# BeautifulSoup - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

The Output says

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = requests.get('https://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=34.05361000000005&lon=-118.24549999999999#.Xy0hrigzaUk')

soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content,'lxml')
week = soup.find(id='seven-day-forecast-body')
items =week.find_all(class_='tombstone-container')
period = [item.find(class_='period-name').get_text() for item in items]
desc = [item.find(class_='short-desc').get_text() for item in items]
temp = [item.find(class_='temp temp-low').get_text() for item in items]
print(period)
print(desc)   
print(temp)
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing  wrong. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

You can add in every line of the list comprehension `if item`

Something like:

`[item.find(class_=???).get_text() for item in items if item]`

The mistake is that some `item` object is actually `None`. Causing this error to raise. If you filter the `None`s, you'll be safe..